# MODx Revo — TV выводится, даже если он пустой. Как исправить?

Tags: modx, revo

Создал tv с названием "formSize", в параметрах вывода указал тег li. Внутри шаблона страницы прописано:

```
[[!getResources? &parents=`[[*id]]` &tpl=`form` &includeTVs=`1` &processTVs=`1`]]
```

В чанке form есть список ul, внутри которого — данный tv. 
(Если tv заполнен, он появляется внутри ul и становится очередным пунктом списка).

Но если tv не заполнен, он выводится как пустой li:

```
<li></li>
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вот вам ресурс, это Сережа Галич, не самое свежее, но актуальности не потеряло!! Ну и немного с матюками, куда же без них))) Главное, разжевано все! http://gaserge.ru/blog/modx-revolution/filtryi-phx-(-modifikatoryi-)-v-modx-revo.html http://gaserge.ru/blog/modx-revolution/sintaksis-tegov-modx-revo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чанке `form` выводите `tv` только если он не пустой, используя модификаторы вывода:

```
[[+formSize:notempty=`[[+formSize]]`]]
```

[Подробнее о модификаторах (англ.)](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-%28output-modifiers%29)

Comment: Я пробовал уже этот вариант, он почему-то не работает. Сейчас ещё раз проверил, использовал [[+tv.formSize:notempty=`[[+tv.formSize]]`]] — пустой тег li всё равно появляется. Без приставки "tv." в чанке поле не выводится вообще.

Comment: Просмотрел, уберите параметрах вывода `tv` поля, тег `li` а в чанке напишите: ``[[+tv.formSize:notempty=`<li>[[+tv.formSize]]</li>`]]``

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло, li больше не появляются. Заодно решилась проблема с ненужными id, которые автоматически создавались в виде "tvformSize" при заполнении tv.